# How to format a json string and show result in table?

Tags: json, web-services, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePhp _serialize method to make a web service and show the data in JSON format.I used the .json extension at the end of the URL to show this data.Now i want to show this data in table.Output image is attached.Is this possible then how i can do it?

Thanks

[image: Output]

Comment: For this to be proper JSON, "task_list" would need to be quoted.

Comment: Which JavaScript frameworks do you use? Do you want to render on the client or parse the JSON in CakePHP and produce HTML on the server?

Comment: it is already quoted

Comment: I want to render on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is a bit odd. I would prefer something like: `"task_list": [ .... ]`; iterating over objects is always a bit tedious.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
var data = ...;
var items = data["task_list"];
var table = $('<table/>');
table.appendTo($('body'));

$.each(items, function(id, value) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    table.append(tr);

    $('<td/>').text(id).appendTo(tr);
    $('<td/>').text(value).appendTo(tr);
});
```

Comment: i should put this one in .ctp file?

Comment: @MoazAteeq: I don't know CakePHP, so I can't answer that. It's a piece of JavaScript; put it where you have the rest of your scripts. You are aware that you need to warp the code in an AJAX request, yes?